# Conditional Formatting Pivot Table based on Dynamic Column Headers

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

thanks for giving a newbie in VBA a little help and guidance.
I am trying to program a macro for conditional formatting in a pivot table(s).

Goal is to find two columns by headers (as their location might change) and apply a conditional formula to one of them. (highlight outlier cells in red)

Headers are in Row 3
Columns starting with A

Example below:

I want to find the column that has Origin Airport,
then find the column that has Origin Handling,
 create a formula the has 2 conditions to compare,e.g. B4 with B5 (match) and D4 with D5 (match) and then highlight any values in Origin Handling (column D) that are not in line, where D4 <> D5.
The following formula I used to test for consistency "=(AND($B4=$B5,D4<>D5)"

! [screenshot of the table] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhNog.jpg)

I have gone through various posts here on SO and put the codes together that i think are applicable. Being a newbie however I am not getting the correct flow, was trying segment by segment but hit a wall when trying to find a code that provides column Letter by find: Header and then creates a formula. Below code sequence is incomplete.

```
    Sub Origin_Charges
        ' Review origin charges based on Consistency
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Origin") 'focuses on the Pivot Table I named Origin'
            Dim ws as worksheet
            Dim rngDateHeader As Range
            Dim rngHeaders As Range
        End with

        Set rngHeaders = Range("3:3") 'Looks in entire first row; adjust as needed.
        Set rngDateHeader = rngHeaders.Find("Origin Airport")
            If rngDateHeader is Nothing then "No Origin Airport Column Found"

        Set rngHeaders = Range("3:3") 'Looks in entire first row; adjust as needed.
        Set rngDateHeader = rngHeaders.Find("Origin Handling")
            If rngDateHeader is Nothing then "No Origin Handling Column Found"

        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
            "=AND($B4=$B5,D4<>D5)" 'Formula right now is fixed but want it to adjust based on what column Origin Airport is in'
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.
        FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With

        With Sheets("Origin")
           .Range("D4").AutoFill .Range("D4:D" & .Cells(.Rows.count,"C")
           .End(xlUp).row)
        End With
    End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which sentence in the above is failing? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `rngDateHeader.EntireColumn.Cells(4).Address(false, false)` for example would give you "B4" if the header was in ColB

Comment: I am missing the logical step from finding the two headers (locations) and then based on the column to create the formula. basically the step after Find("Origin Handling") to programming the formula.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks Tim, how would I be able to have the formula capture B4 in your example?

Comment: found this code: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014492/excel-vba-that-searches-by-header-name-not-column)     He is using a vlookup as part of his formula. Is there a way to incorporate the rngeheader.find / Tim's suggestion as part of the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim c As Range, sht As Worksheet, f as string

Set sht = Activesheet

Set c = sht.Cells(4, rngDateHeader.Column) 'eg B4

f = "=AND(" & c.address(false, false) & "=" & _
     c.offset(1,0).address(false, false) & ",D4<>D5)"  '<< use formula f in your CF
```